# Are Drasilian coins only for selling?

Tags: dragon-quest-xi

NPCs in *Dragon Quest XI S* say that Drasilian coins are the only item I don’t need to hold onto, I can sell them all. Is this correct or do I need them for a quest or crafting later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as the NPCs say, Drasilian coins are never useful for anything besides selling for money. No quest or exchange requires them, and they are used in no forging recipes. Sell them to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't completed the game, and I'm playing the version on PS4, but I would guess that if in the description of the item it's written 'Has no value, can be sold for coins' the logic would be it's their only use.

If they flip that on you late game, and decide that 'oh now you need them' when they told you before they basically have no use, it would be bad design. So I'm willing to bet they can be sold without danger.